# What is the exact difference among punctuations “a”, ‘a’ and `a in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb, punctuation

My question is about the punctuation marks in DolphinDB. I wrote the line `table.select("*").where(f"interval='d'")` and it cannot retrieve the data, but `table.select("*").where(f"interval=`d")` works when I replaced the marks. Here the interval is SYMBOL type.

I’m wondering what is the difference between single quotes, double quotes, and backquotes in DolphinDB? Is there any efficient way to differentiate their uses?
I've looked through similar questions but didn't get clear answers. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the data type for one character, single quotes are used to create a CHAR type in DolphinDB. Use function `typestr` to check the data type:
[image]

The marks you mentioned can all be used in other type declaration cases as long as it’s not for one character as they all refer to STRING type. SYMBOL is a special type of STRING.
More information from DolphinDB tutorial:

- Back quotes are very convenient, but they cannot be used for strings that contain spaces or symbols.
- To create a string with only one character, we can use back quotes or double quotes but not single quotes. Single quotes around one character create a CHAR instead of STRING.